# Laravel eagerloading not working

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to utilize Laravels eagerlaoding functionality, but it doesn't at all behave like expected.

I've tried following the official examples, but I cannot reproduce their behavior.

I have a `Product` class which `hasMany('OrderLine')` meaning actual orders for this product.

I'd like to eagerload the lines, when displaying the products and their orders count, so I do this:

```
$products = Product::with('OrderLines')->get();
foreach($products as $product) {
  var_dump($product->orderlines->first());
};
```

This should work fine, right?

Well, when I check the SQL log, this happens:

```
[SQL] select * from "products" 
      bindings: []
      time: 0.71 milliseconds
[SQL] select * from "order_lines" where "order_lines"."product_id" in (?, ?, ?, ?) 
      bindings: [2,3,4,5]
      time: 0.79 milliseconds
[SQL] select * from "order_lines" where "order_lines"."product_id" = ? 
      bindings: [2]
      time: 0.32 milliseconds
[SQL] select * from "order_lines" where "order_lines"."product_id" = ? 
      bindings: [3]
      time: 0.3 milliseconds
[SQL] select * from "order_lines" where "order_lines"."product_id" = ? 
      bindings: [4]
      time: 0.31 milliseconds
[SQL] select * from "order_lines" where "order_lines"."product_id" = ? 
      bindings: [5]
      time: 0.29 milliseconds
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around why Laravel/Eloquent behaves this way. First it correctly eagerloads the lines, but then it ignores the preloaded orderlines when I loop over the products...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop `orderlines` this way:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
  foreach ($product->orderlines as $ol) {
    echo $ol->name;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've checked it and the problem is case of letters.

If your relation has name `orderLines` you should use:

```
$products = Product::with('orderLines')->get();

foreach($products as $product) {
  foreach ($product->orderLines $ol) {
    echo $ol->name;
  }
}
```

so in all places you should use `orderLines` exactly the same - not in one place `OrderLines` and in the other `orderlines`

Comment: That doesn't work... the loop runs fine, but the log shows the same N+1 query as in my code.

Comment: The same six queries, which should be just two queries.

Comment: You are right. It's a character case issue. `with` and the association attribute must be written in identical case.